# I want to get the size of file i select in MBs from internal storage of my phone. but file.length() always returns 0

Tags: java, android, file, size

I am able to select a pdf type file from the internal storage of my phone. I want to get the size of a file in MBs and to put limit on file select based on its size. But following code always returns 0 although the file has been successfully selected.

```
String uriString = PostFileUri.toString();
File myFile = new File(uriString);
// Get length of file in bytes
long fileSizeInBytes = myFile.length();
// Convert the bytes to Kilobytes (1 KB = 1024 Bytes)
long fileSizeInKB = fileSizeInBytes / 1024;
// Convert the KB to MegaBytes (1 MB = 1024 KBytes)
long fileSizeInMB = fileSizeInKB / 1024;
Log.i("FileSize", String.valueOf(fileSizeInMB));
```

Comment: what is the value of `myFile.length()` ?

Comment: It always returns 0

Answer (score 0):

Probably, you've got a **0**, because you didn't get an existing file. Try this

```
    File rootStorage = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
    File myFile = new File(rootStorage.toString() + "/download/q1.jpeg");//or whatever  
    long fileSizeInBytes =  myFile.length();
    // Convert the bytes to Kilobytes (1 KB = 1024 Bytes)
    long fileSizeInKB = fileSizeInBytes / 1024;
    // Convert the KB to MegaBytes (1 MB = 1024 KBytes)
    long fileSizeInMB = fileSizeInKB / 1024;
    Log.i("FileSize",String.valueOf(fileSizeInMB));
```

Comment: I always get file as its name appears and when i upload to firebase it actually uploaded

Comment: Then try to use something like this:   new FileOutputStream(**your file here**).getChanel.size(); (PS. I didn't test it, because I don't have an ability to do this...)

Comment: Futhermore, I've been stucked with the same issue in my project.